# Smart Contract firing send ether transaction that's not in the contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, rinkeby, geth-debugging, aws

I need some help with my smart contract, here's the smart contract code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract UserToken {
    mapping (bytes32 => uint8) public tokenBalance;

    bytes32[] public userList;

    // Constructor
    function UserToken(bytes32[] userName) public payable {
        userList = userName;
    }

    // Returns the total votes a candidate has received
    function totalTokensFor(bytes32 user) view public returns (uint8) {
        require(validUser(user));
        return tokenBalance[user];
    }

    // Increments the token count of user
    function buyToken(bytes32 user, uint8 token) public {
        require(validUser(user));
        tokenBalance[user] += token;
    }

    function validUser(bytes32 user) view public returns (bool) {
        for(uint i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
          if (userList[i] == user) {
            return true;
          }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I have a geth node connected to rinkeby and running on my ec2 instance in AWS, from there I've created the eth account address and then imported the JSON file to metamask.

Now this is the problem, whenever I call the function "**buyToken**", it fires four transactions
[image]

The first transaction is this https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x3206678cdd6fdcfc4eddf3871002b77320d5e83f3bb5f9e2d9c0c0aa9bbc8817

An ether transfer to another address w/c is not in the contract, and the ether it transferred was `2.994817 Ether`, again not in the contract, thus making the next three transactions disappear since there’s not enough balance in the account, original account balance was 3 ether.

Here's the code that calls the BuyToken

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var userContract = web3.eth.contract(ABI);
var userInstance = userContract.at(contract address)

$("#buy_button").click(function(e) {
    let tx_hash = userInstance.buyToken("John", 3);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

My question is why is this happening? There aren't any ether transfer code in my contract so what's the possible cause of this?

Thanks

Comment: Where's the code that actually generates these transactions? You've shared the contract code but not where you're calling `buyToken`.

Comment: @smarx ive updated my post

Comment: I don't think that the code you've shared is what's generating those transactions. For one thing, that code only generates a single transaction, and you're seeing several. But also, the transaction you shared isn't a call to a contract at all. (The `data` field is empty.)

Comment: You mentioned MetaMask, but the code you shared doesn't use MetaMask. What am I missing?

Comment: @smarx Yes it's not using metamask, im just using metamask to quickly check the balance of the account i created, another weird thing is that it's working fine in my local machine, same setup, but when i try to do the transaction in the web app in aws that's when it fires multiple transactions

Comment: I've also removed the payable modifier in the constructor, still the same problem

Comment: I'm confused about your setup. When you're using the web app in AWS, how does `localhost` work? Are you running a browser inside the VM in AWS?

Comment: Yes, i have a django application in AWS, then that web app is using web3 to communicate w/ the geth node, the node is also in AWS VM, so I have two running web app, and two running ethereum geth full node, 1 in my local machine and one in AWS, they are all using the same contract deployed in rinkeby, and both node is using the same account, i just imported the account's keystore from my local machine to AWS

Comment: Again, in my local machine it only fires 1 transaction so it works no problem, but in AWS, buytoken is firing multiple transactions and the first one is an ether transfer, here's the latest transaction triggered by BuyToken in AWS

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xfe6c15f1d05231dcdc079bfcb044fb426c929305dcbf3dcd7b840a9c7c4a424a

Comment: I think there's some confusion. `buyToken` isn't triggering any transactions... it's never getting called in the first place. Is the geth instance on AWS accessible from outside the VM? Or do firewall rules prevent that? I'm wondering if this is essentially a hack... some automated process that perhaps doesn't realize the node is only connected to Rinkeby.

Comment: If you transfer some ether to that account and then do nothing (don't try to call `buyToken` or anything else), I wonder if a transaction will come in sending the ether elsewhere. If so, I'd be fairly confident it's someone automating ether theft.

Comment: (But do make sure the account is unlocked, since an attacker wouldn't be able to unlock the account themselves.)

Comment: I should clarify that `buyToken` is perhaps being called (though not in the transaction you linked to). But the ether transfers are completely unrelated to your contract.

Comment: @smarx yes geth instance on AWS is accessible outside VM, i can telnet 8545 from my local machine, will try your suggestion of transferring ether to the recipient's account, problem is I already used all my social media account to get tokens from the faucet so will need to wait 7more hours

Comment: Recipients of the ether transfers are actually different

Answer (score 0):

Why are you referring to Etherscan for Rinkeby when your code is clearly pointed at your own local chain? http://localhost:8545 not a Rinkeby provider.

Your link to Rinkeby is likely from someone else's action entirely it appears, and your code is pointing at your own local instance of geth

Comment: My geth full node in AWS is a live node connected to rinkeby, that's why, and my web app is in the same AWS VM instance where my full node is running

Answer (score 0):

This is not due to your contract and this is due to your network setup.
  Please check the network where you have connected, Your problem seems you are creating your own network. Lets come to problem. Such a problem may happen due following configuration you made -

**Your network setup**

- You configured your node running in AWS is validating node.
- You Enabled the RPC port in same validating node.
- You unlocked account so your validating node works fine.

This is due to geth had this problem and many times we faced this problem. Disable rpc port of validating node and add one more node to interact with the blockchain, this node should do not have any unlocked account so your geth cannot automatically sent ether to arbitrary account.
Hope it helps!